# ActiveRecord Nested Associations Many-To-One

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a schema like so...

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :foo
    belongs_to :bar
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars
end
```

I'm trying to get all three objects nested and broken down in JSON so I have the following code...

```
foo = Foo.first
foo.to_json(:include => {:bars => :baz})
```

But I'm getting the following exception...

can't clone Symbol
file: try.rb location: clone line: 36

I'd like to get Foo with all the bars nested and the bars with all the baz's nested. Is that possible?

I hope my attempt to keep the example abstract makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way to nest models on to_json method is the following:

```
foo.to_json(:include => { :bars => { :include => { :baz } } }
```

According to the api for [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)
method.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same "can't clone Symbol file" error while rendering json from a controller method. avoided it like so:

```
render :json => @team.to_json( :include => [:members] )
```